# How to display message before redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, message

I have to display message before redirect and it has to be without header refresh - because I can't use that on my hosting. I made it with JavaScript but what if someone has not JavaScript enabled? Which way is suitable for this case? here's my controller:

```html
 public function code_check()
    {      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'Code', 'trim|required'); 
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {

            $this->index();
        }
        else 
        {
            if($this->user_model->code_check()) {
                redirect('index/results_show');
            } else {
                echo "Wrong code!";
                  echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = '/survey/index.php/home/index/';\",1500);</script>";            
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you use [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)?

Comment: I believe that Javascript is a proper-way to do your redirects, Now days, it's pretty rare to see people browsing with Javascript disabled, Plus Javascript is growing really fast, I wouldn't worry about people not using Javascript, they are probably not your audience anyways.